# exception while connecting SciDB via JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, scidb

I am using SciDB 12.04, Ubuntu 12.04 protobuf-java-2.6.1

I am traying to  connect the Java code with SciDB .. So i installed JDBC14.12 
I follow the instruction inside the [manual](http://www.paradigm4.com/HTMLmanual/14.12/scidb_ug/ch09.html) , when i tried the sample code [test](http://www.paradigm4.com/HTMLmanual/14.12/scidb_ug/ch09s05.html) (as descibed at the manual) I got this error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is supposed to be overridden by subclasses.
```

Comment: using protobuf-java-2.6.1

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @vault I just run the sample code from the manual [basic links](http://www.paradigm4.com/HTMLmanual/14.12/scidb_ug/ch09s05.html)

Comment: so you downloaded the jar and tried to run it  as described? `java -classpath example.jar:$CLASSPATH org.scidb.JDBCExample`

Comment: @vault ..yes 
download it  using :'code' (wget http://downloads.paradigm4.com/client/14.12/jdbc/example.jar)

then i tried to run it using : java -classpath example.jar:$CLASSPATH org.scidb.JDBCExample

Comment: ok, last 3 questions: 1) can you post the entire stack trace? 2) is your classpath correct? 3) are you sure scidb is running on localhost?

Comment: @vault answers:
1) i dont know how to get the stack trace
2) yes i think the classpath is correct: 
export CLASSPATH=~/JDBC/scidb4j.jar:/usr/share/java/protobuf-java.jar
I add it using the terminal and the modify the bashrc file 

3) yes the scidb and ssh is running ..

Comment: @vault I have 2 users the scidb and the root 
if i tried to download and run the test example using the scidb user i get another error which is 
(
Driver is not in the CLASSPATH -> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.scidb.jdbc.Driver
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:scidb://localhost:1239/

)

the first error description while iam using the root user

Comment: Sounds like you are using protobuf 2.4.x classes with protobuf 2.5 or newer; or at least I have seen the same exception with a service using protobuf where there was a protobuf library mismatch.

Comment: As implied: check the versions of your dependencies; you might be using a newer version of protobuf than other parts in your application expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution... thank u for ur suggestions ..

I sloved the problem in 2 steps:

1. use java 1.6 rather than 1.7
2. use  libprotobuf-java 2.4.1-1ubuntu2 rather than protobuf-java-2.6.1

So it was versions conflict problem